# Wpf line with variable thickness

Tags: wpf, xaml

Is there any way to create lines (Xaml), with different thickness, like this:

[image]

I have one solution: closed path with fill. Is there another one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try it with an ink object, i.e. Stroke with a few StylusPoints that have a pressure. But whether pressure will be rendered as varying thickness might depend on other things as well. I guess, the best way is still the path in this case.

Comment: Well, accept it after you have verified that it works :-). As of now I have no idea; it was just a thought. I have never worked with ink (except as an end user on my tablet).

Answer (score 0):

The only other way I see would be to create a custom control that would do it. Otherwise, I believe a path is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

You could draw multiple lines and connect them. Maybe you could apply some kind of transformation matrix, but I also have no clue how exactly this could work.

Answer (score 0):

this is pretty much what Path is for